# ftpcmd.bat not uploading the complete pdf file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I am using this code to upload via a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo user user@site.com> ftpcmd.dat
echo password>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd public_html/new/data>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put abc.pdf>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 11.111.111.111
del ftpcmd.dat
```

If I upload this same file (4MB pdf) with filezilla, it uploads in its entirety to the public_html/new/data folder. I have uploaded many files without issues, mainly txt, htm, csv and xls files and have never had an issue with the above code.

But for this pdf file it shows the same size of file as having been uploaded, but when I open the file I get an error message that is has been corrupted and it only partially displays the page contents.

I have tried removing the @echo off and setting the folder permissions to 777, but I end up with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows [`ftp` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp) supports an [ASCII (text) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-ascii) and a [binary mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-binary), the former of which is the default setting.

In text mode (entered by the command `ascii`), end-of-line markers become converted, and end-of-file characters may be recognised. In binary mode however (entered by the command `binary`), no such conversions occur and files remain unedited.

Since a PDF file is not a text file, binary mode is required; otherwise, its contents becomes altered, rendering the file corrupt.